# Can't format TrueCtypt file container to NTFS

Tags: truecrypt

I'm following standard procedure for creating encrypted file container, and then formatting to NTFS, the progress reaches 100%, waits for a while, and then gives me this:

[image: Windows failed to format the volume as NTFS.]

Formatting to FAT succeeds. I'm using Windows 8 Pro x64. I've tried different sizes for container from 512Mb (smallest size supported by NTFS AFAIK) to 2Gb.

Comment: how big is the container?

Comment: @Keltari I've tried different sizes for container from 512Mb (smallest size supported by NTFS AFAIK) to 2Gb.

Comment: Do you have UAC enabled, and if so, are you running TrueCrypt as Administrator?

Comment: @Huskehn UAC is disabled, and I'm running TrueCrypt as admin anyway.